# Limit a class to include only functions with a specific signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my app I have several classes which are used to create XML strings.
Each class has a few methods that take some arguments and return a string. I want to specify this limitation so that methods with a different signature or other class members can't be added. To this end, here's where I got so far:

```
interface IRequestParser {
  [funcName: string]: (...args: any[]) => string;
}
```

and an example of a class:

```
class myParser implements IRequestParser {
  [funcName: string]: (...args: any[]) => string;

  func1(a) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

This prevents me from adding functions that don't return strings, or any other non-method member, so these aren't allowed inside `myParser`:

```
  a: string; // not allowed
  b() { // not allowed
    return 5;
  }
```

However, this has the effect of letting me call any function name from an instance of `myParser` without an alert:

```
const a = new myParser();
console.log(a.func1('a'));
console.log(a.func2(4, 5, ['s', 'b']));
```

The call to `func1` makes sense and I would also get an error if I didn't supply a value for its argument `a`. However, I can also call non-existing function `func2` and any other name.

Is there a way to both limit the type of class members while also avoiding this situation of calling any function with any name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
class MyParser implements Record<keyof MyParser, (...args: any[]) => string> {

  // okay
  func1(a: any) {
    return '';
  }

  // error: string is not assignable to (...args: any[]) => string
  a: string; 

  // error: number is not assignable to string
  b() { 
    return 5;
  }
}

const myParser = new MyParser();
myParser.func1("okay"); // works
myParser.funcNope("huh"); // error, no property funcNope
```

It's permissible to implement a concrete mapped type (like `Record<>`), and it is sometimes possible to have circular references (referring to keys via `keyof` is usually acceptable).

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This seems more direct and gives more explicit error messages. The `Record` type is what I was missing. I'll accept this.

Comment: I'm a bit upset with myself that I did not thing to use `keyof` in the `implements` clause. It makes sense you can do it since implementations are just checked after the class is checked so keys should be known. Nice answer :)

Comment: Personally I'm still confused as to how a type can be defined with its own `keyof`, where usually you can't define a type using itself so that it's recursive. Is there a place I could read more about it?

Comment: I'm noticing that in classes inheriting from `MyParser` the limitation is lifted, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: No, it doesn't propagate down.  If you really need that you might want to go back to an index signature like `[whoKnows: string]: undefined | ((...args: any[]) => string)`.  That does have the problem that `myParser.funcNope` will not be an error itself, but at least its type includes `undefined` (assuming you use `--strictNullChecks` which you really should) so if try to call `myParser.funcNope()` you will get an error.

Comment: using `undefined |  ((...args: any[]) => string)` doesn't seem to work in TS playground, the type of functions (existing or otherwise) is assumed to be `any[] => string` and no error is brought up when calling a nonexistent function.

Comment: You need `--strictNullChecks` on for it to work (I kind of hate the fact that you can turn `--strictNullChecks` off at all)

Answer (score 3):

The interface you use allows the class to be indexed by any string. We can't express the constraint you want with an interface (at least no way I can think of, maybe someone else has an idea).

You could use a function to constrain the class to only have functions with the signature while preserving the actual properties the class has:

```
type ParserFn = (...args: any[]) => string;
function createRequestParserClass<
  T extends new (...a: any[]) => Record<keyof InstanceType<T>, ParserFn>>(ctor: T) {
  return ctor
}
const myParser = createRequestParserClass(class {
  // a: string; // not allowed
  // b() { // not allowed
  //   return 5;
  // }

  func1(a: string) {
    return '';
  }
});
```

type myParser = InstanceType

```
const a = new myParser();
console.log(a.func1('a'));
console.log(a.func2(4, 5, ['s', 'b'])); // error now 
console.log(a.func1(1)); // also error
```

Comment: I will test this out. If I want to define the class somewhere, and create an instance elsewhere, then I can define the inner class in a file, and then rather than create it I should call `createRequestParserClass`? Maybe make the constructor private and add this function to each class to prevent creating the raw class?

Comment: @RanLottem you can use  the const `myParser`as you would any other class. In conjunction with the type `myParser` (I added after the original answer) the two should work pretty much as a regular function definition. If you want to use `myParser ` in another  file export both and it should work

Comment: It seems that trying to add class members of the wrong type results in an error when calling `createRequestParserClass`, rather than at the definition of the inner class (which is what I was looking for with the "interface extension" method I tried). Still, I learned a lot from this solution, thanks.

Comment: @RanLottem yes the error will be reported on the function call not the class itself. I personally don't think it matters much, an error is an error, but its up to you if this makes this solution unusable for you.

Comment: @RanLottem did not see jcalz's answer last night, he's is definitely better :-)